# Xcode crash on opening .xcodeproj file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I am running my React-Native iOS project with Xcode but I don't know which change effects it and my I notices that my Xcode is crashed then I try to open it inside Xcode but it crashes every time then I deleted derived data and also `xcuserdata` from `.xcodeproj` file but no success I also tried to use this command "defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode" but again no luck I have also looked into `.xcodeproj` file for conflicts but there is no conflicts I try to run my project with command line but again got this message.

```
"error Failed to build iOS project. We ran `xcodebuild` command but it exited with error code null. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening `.xcodeproj`
```

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this ?

Delete derived data of xcode and also of project.
react-native run-ios

```
"error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code null. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Raydan.xcodeproj"
```

Comment: try opening `.xcworkspace`

Comment: It sounds like your Xcode project got corrupted. If you use git, you can check which commits may have caused this. Try to recover your project from previous git commits.

Comment: @Asleepace i tried with .xcworkspace file and its same.

Comment: @Amar i also checkout the previous commits but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried almost everything on the internet like.

1. Deleting Xcode `derived data`.
2. Try with `.workspace file`.
3. Deleting `xcuserData`.

but nothing works, At last, I found this problem with `react-native-fast-image`, upgrading to `react-native-fast-image v7.0.0` was causing the problem so downgrading `react-native-fast-image` to `v5.1.2` works for me.

here is the issue reported in their Github.

https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues/527

Comment: You are a life saver :D

Comment: Glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience working with React-Native and XCode you should try deleting the **build** folder for android and/or iOS for whichever you are using it for. Every time you run your code it should re-create a new build once it is deleted.

Comment: Also tried with deleting the build folder but same.

Comment: have you tried going inside the 'ios' folder and running **pod install** ?

Comment: @Vinnaey i am not using pod so there is not any pod file inside ios folder.